# Java/MySQL - Retrieve ID from last record saved

Tags: java, mysql

Can anyone help me out please? I am trying to retrieve ID(primary key) at the time the record is created and set it to a textfield. Currently, all it returns is 1 all the time. 
My current approach looks like this:

```
connection = Utilities.getConnection();
            String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO student_details (Name, Surname, Date_Of_Birth, Gender, Address, Post_Code, Mobile_Number)" + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, txtFirstName.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, txtSurname.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, String.valueOf(dpDateOfBirth.getValue()));
            preparedStatement.setString(4, cbGender.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, txtAddress.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(6, txtPostCode.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(7, txtMobileNo.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            txtStudentID.setText(String.valueOf(preparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS));
            Utilities.showInforMsg("Record Saved:", "Record has been saved.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the generated key via:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();

if (rs.next()) {
    key = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

what you are doing with this line

```
txtStudentID.setText(String.valueOf(preparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS));
```

is setting the student id to the value of the constant of the Statement interface (see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)